# Monitor User App Usage From Mac OS X App

Tags: objective-c, macos, monitoring

I am interested in building a Mac OS X application that requires knowing what applications the user has open and when a new one opens, all when my app is running. It doesn't have to be approved by the Mac App Store (If this violates their use terms). An example of an app that does this is the Rescue Time app.

Thank you for any answers,
Michael Truell

Comment: Did you find a solution to your answer?

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't @SteffenAndersen

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you're still trying to needs this, but I did some more research on how to solve this and here is what you could look into:

To get notified when applications are opened by a user, use NSWorkspace's notification center, and add an observer for keys like NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification. See the documentation [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html). You can also use NSWorkspace to get all running applications.

If you need to access information about a running application, you should check out [Scripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html), and if you don't care about App Store or sandboxing, check you accessibility api, [AX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/AboutOSXAccessibility/AboutOSXAccessibility.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001078)